# Is this long black insect with semi-long antennae and a large segmented abdomen caught in the kitchen a larva or an imago? And what is it?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This is in Northrhine Westfalia in Germany/Europe: we have those large longish and comparatively flat bugs (taking my hand below the plastic as reference, it should be about 4cm or 1 5/8in in length) or larvae in our kitchen occasionally.  For a larva, it seems to be lacking any soft parts.  It can raise its behind "threateningly" in the style of a scorpion but I doubt it's anything but mimicry.  Its large head reminds me of ant soldiers, though it is obviously out of scale.  I think it's mostly in the evening or night that we find one (and it's often because a cat stares at it in an obvious manner) and while it's usually the kitchen, that may just be because we are most frequently there.

[image: large larva/imago caught in kitchen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an adult rove beetle (Coleptera, Staphilinidae). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rove_beetle 
Rove beetles have very short elytra (forewings), so they don't look like other beetles. This one looks a lot like *Ocypus olens*, which is common in Europe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_coach_horse_beetle

Comment: The Wikimedia image https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Staphylinus.olens.jpg looks so very much like my photograph (the exemplar there looks a bit less shabby) that it's almost like I copied it.  I am pretty sure that my exemplar exceeded the Wikipedia entry's given size range (up to 32mm) though.  At least the name "Devil's coach horse beetle" (though nothing in the description found there) suggests that I should have included the information that we live on riding school premises with one paddock right next to the kitchen windows.  Thanks!